# How do I modify my javascript code to alert this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, templates, google-maps

http://geodit.com:8000/test

If you go to my site, you'll see that you I installed Google Local Search API.
Basically, it hits Google via javascript and performs a search.

After someone searches something and clicks on one of the results, how can I alert the address?  (right now, some sill info white box pops up on the map. I don't want that. i just want to alert the address)

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/events.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the

```
LocalResult.prototype.select = function() {
  unselectMarkers();
  this.selected_ = true;
  this.highlight(true);
  gInfoWindow.setContent(this.html(true));
  gInfoWindow.open(gMap, this.marker());
};
```

to

```
LocalResult.prototype.select = function() {
      unselectMarkers();
      this.selected_ = true;
      this.highlight(true);
      var msg = 'Address\n\t';
      msg += this.result_.addressLines.join('\n\t');
      msg += '\nCity\n\t';
      msg += this.result_.city;
      msg += '\nCountry\n\t';
      msg += this.result_.country;
      alert(msg);
};
```

Comment: Thanks ! This works. How did you know "addressLines" and "city" and "country" What API page did you use to see those properties?

Comment: @Timex, I used firebug to examine the *`this`* object when it referred to `LocalResult`. (*used in the above function the `console.log(this)`*)